# Issues with using elementree to edit attributes in an XML file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having issues editing attributes within a specific XML document.  I've figured out how to pull the attribute with the 'findall' feature, but I can't seem to find a valid way to write a new attribute into the field.  Can someone show me the syntax used in editing a specific XML element?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement

input = '''
<Configuration>
    <UserInterface>
        <OSD>
            <HalfwakeMessage>Attribute to edit.</HalfwakeMessage>
        </OSD>
    </UserInterface>
</Configuration>'''
stuff=ET.fromstring(input)

lst=stuff.findall('UserInterface/OSD')

for i in lst:
    x=i.find('HalfwakeMessage')
    print(x)
```

Comment: confirming one of the answers you can get +2 reputation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use **text** property.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement

input = '''
<Configuration>
    <UserInterface>
        <OSD>
            <HalfwakeMessage>Attribute to edit.</HalfwakeMessage>
        </OSD>
    </UserInterface>
</Configuration>'''

print(input)

stuff = ET.fromstring(input)
print(stuff)

lst=stuff.findall('UserInterface/OSD')

for i in lst:
    x=i.find('HalfwakeMessage')
    print(x.text)
    x.text = 'New text'
    print(x.text)


output = ET.tostring(stuff)
print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This seems to work in the for loop, but how do I write the results back out to the "input" variable.  I tried using the "write" feature but I get a traceback stating that there is no 'write' attribute.

Comment: Hi @BrianGrace, I have added 2 more lines there. You can simply convert your XML back to string :)

Comment: @BrianGrace, does it solve your issue or do you have some other problems?

Answer (score 0):

To edit an element, use [insert](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.insert) or [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set)

Comment: I've tried using set on this specific XML and have had no success.  Can you possibly elaborate on how I would use set or insert in this case?

Comment: I believe the documentation is enough to give you instructions on it. Usage is like `ele.insert(0, SomeElement)` or `ele.set('src', 'https://someimage.png')`. Also to modify text inside an element, you can use `ele.text = 'SomeText'` as Boris pointed out above.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  The example Boris gave seems to work.  I had no success using insert or set.